# IIS worker process is getting crashed

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis-8.5, w3wp

Application: ASP.NET, C#
Framework: 4.6.2
Authentication mode:- Windows Authentication-Allow.
Platform:64-bit
Server: Win-2012
IIS:8.5
Is being migrated to Azure platform. In testing phase - automated test tool, sends rapid requests. Those requests could be anything like, dummy requests, malicious requests, page doesn't exists, page with inserted javascript or existing page with wrong parameters. etc. Basically tool will try to break/hack your application. Somehow as soon as this tool start testing, our app-pool is getting crashed. Sometimes it runs for a while but doesn't go long. During testing when we monitored IIS worker process crashes frequently.
Where as manual browser testing works fine.

I have tried following things:
1. Verified CPU and memory usage, they are normal.
2. Verified http logs: Those requests which are captured shows correct error codes. E.g. Page which doesn't exits shows 500, lot of request shows unauthorized 401.1, some correct request will also shows 200.
3. Application is set for Windows Authentication-Allow mode. Automated test tool uses some valid credentials. Though we see lot of requests are unauthorized.
4. Tried with different machines and different user credentials, every time IIS crashes.
5. Issue is reproducible at both DEV and UAT environments.
6. Was able to pull crash dumps but not able to read/debug it as of now. doing research on how to read them.
7. Application is writing logs into db. But that is not costly operation too. It may not be the root cause. Since sometimes with first or second request also it will start failing.
8. Compared with application those pass these kind of testing, nothing special in our configuration.
9. Tried changing requests per seconds. It didn't help.
10. Verified application event logs: it mainly shows following 2 errors.

A) Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19153, time stamp: 0x5b93ffa7
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000030461
Faulting process id: 0x4d48
Faulting application path: C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

B) Same error with clr.dll.

So not able to find the exact reason why the worker process is keep getting crashed. IIS will allow 5 recycling in a row and then stops doing it then the application will remain in unavailable state (503 error).
Appreciate any suggestions/hints to reach to the root cause.

Comment: In case it helps, 0xc00000fd is "STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW". Perhaps something going wrong in the error handling that doesn't get executed during normal browsing behavior. Years ago, I ran into an issue where the error logging function failed because of permissions and caught an exception, which called the error logging function to log the error - causing an endless recursive loop - causing a stack overflow. Not sure if that's your case, but its something that stuck with me ever since.

Comment: Thanks @Wiz for quick response. I have validated it already. The logging is happening successfully in database and in file based as well. Basically tool is just sending rapid wrong requests. Application uses it's own service accounts to log to file/db, which has correct permissions and hence able to log it successfully. Initially I thought there would be load/overflow on it, however with very few requests also it fails. However I agree with 0xc00000fd it is overflow, but where it is. That I am not able to locate. Thanks.

Comment: If you are not experienced on crash analysis, please open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com

Comment: @Wiz, looks like I got some clue, when I revisited logging code. Working on it, will keep you posted.

Comment: I got the crash dump logs and I can see some recursion code/calls.At the end it shows following.Can some1 confirm if this is Enterprize Library's problem or our code's prob?
ntdll.dll!RtlpReAllocateHeap() 
ntdll.dll!RtlReAllocateHeap()
mscorlib.ni.dll!00007ffc589e6929()
[Managed to Native Transition]
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName()
mscorlib.dll!System.Type.GetType()
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.RetrieveConfigurationElementType()
MS.Entp.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement()
System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement()
<App recursion code>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So there were two things.
1. Why the app pool was crashing? 
Looking at the event log it was clean that there was overflow. 
2. However I didn't know where it was. For that I look into crash dump. I got the location. Then I fixed it. Thanks @Wiz, it was into logging code.